# Java library for PDF reader supporting highlighting

Tags: java, pdf, highlighting

I would like to build my own **pdf-reader in Java** and would like to have the possibility to **highlight words** in the pdf and save these highlights.

1. I have seen there exist several PDF libraries I can use, but I wonder which would be best to use for this purpose.
2. Is it possible to do this kind of highlighting, and is there a specific library or so to help me do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a big list of Open Source [pdf libraries](http://java-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries) for java. I haven't used any of them but I'll bet for pdfBox that's part of Apache Foundation. It has a specific class to [highlight](http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/highlighting.html) PDFs in xml but I think you also have to rebuid them.

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/package-summary.html) Library. It provide highlight option for search terms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Apache PDFBox for highlighting in PDF.

Link: https://pdfbox.apache.org/